# how nodejs work? how eventloop works? what is worker thread?

Tags: node.js, threadpool, event-loop

How nodejs work?
I read the nodejs official documentation many times, i couldn't understand what exactly the meant,

What I understood is, whenever a nodejs program starts the eventloop also starts.

Offical Documentations says

> The event loop is what allows Node.js to perform non-blocking I/O operations — despite the fact that JavaScript is single-threaded — by offloading operations to the system kernel whenever possible.

Event loop has 5 phases,

- Timers
- Pending Callbacks
- Idle-Prepare (Dont know what exactly its is)
- Poll
- Check
- Close Callbacks

> There is a slight discrepancy between the Windows and the Unix/Linux implementation,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNa9OMajw9w

I viewed above video many times, its very difficult to understand his presentation,
In this video Bert is the speaker one of nodejs core developer in windows OS

Comment: Do you have a specific question? This question(s) seem too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

So what is a thread? Think of it as a smallest unit of instruction that a cpu can process independently! This thread is responsible for execution of a program instruction supplied at a time. When it comes to multi-threading it depends upon the capability of your CPU and OS architecture if it supports multi-threading capabilities or not. If it does generally it is the work of a scheduler (present in the OS) to create threads that run concurrently.
Multi-threading is a similar concept , it is the capability of a CPU and OS to run multiple threads of the same application at the same time. And wait that is f** awesome, I mean if my application runs simultaneously on multiple threads (say 4) then my app will do the instructions provided at godspeed and ez pz done!

Well that is not the case lol, Java and C++ are great examples of multi-threaded languages but when it comes to JavaScript (EcmaScript) the only issue is the usecase (keep in mind always always and always that languages work according to the use case)

So what is the BIG Problem? JavaScript (majorly used in web applications) needs to interact with the DOM quite often (almost always quite often in vague sense) now let's assume for a second that JS is multi-threaded, we deploy our application and the user comes and clicks a button, since multi-threading is present it fires several events NOT JUST ONE, since there are several things happening in the background,

Thread #1: Handle the User Click Event
Thread #2: Get browser to get ready for the re-render
Thread #3: Re-render something that is affected by that click
Thread #4: Handle something else

Now the fun begins, each and every thread will get their job and say alright let's do this, What is the first step? (edited)

The first step is to create a Virtual DOM and then compare it with the real DOM and render the things that are required.

Thread #3: Done!
Thread #1: What? WTF? The user click is not handled yet!
Thread #3: Wait but the user clicked right?
Thread#1: Yes he did; but what about the data that I needed to give you?
Thread #3: Oh wait lol, I needed data xD
Thread #2: Guys I am ready for the re-render!
Thread #1 has left the chat!

this is the main issue with multi-threading (edited)

Multi-threading is simply not possible because of the nature JS and the DOM works. So what should we do?

Welcome the hot and sexy neighbor called the Event Loop why is it hot and sexy? Because it can replicate the exact same multi-threading behavior that is actually single threaded!

The Event loop interacts with the call stack, the event handler queue, and the JS Web APIs,
NOTE: JS is single-threaded but not the native Browser or the Web APIs, they are multi-threaded (edited)

All the event loop does is to check weather the event handler queue has something pending? And if the call stack is empty, if this is the case then it puts the next event in the call stack and removes it from the event handler queue. This exact behavior is what makes the work done by browser look multi-threaded whereas in actual being single threaded.

Also key thing to note, that I forgot to add, each and every window of a WebWorker has its own Event Loop

> 

Hope you found that useful!

Comment: Can you format better your answer? will be better to new people read and understand. If you want to use images, you can too!